# Using KDE Dolphin to connect to a remote machine

Tags: ssh, kde-plasma

I know I can use KDE dolphin to open a directory in a remote machine that I can directly access via ssh, but what if that machine is 1 hop away? Normally, when I have to open a terminal on such machine (let's call it `destination`), I issue the following command:

```
ssh user1@intermediate_destination:dir1
```

which allows me to connect to an "intermediate" server. Then, from `intermediate_destination`:

```
ssh user2@destination:dir2
```

How do I open a file browser in `destination` from my local machine using KDE Dolphin?

Comment: try googleing "ssh tunnelling". Once you set up a tunnel, you can ask dolphin to connect to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @sanette, I've tried setting up an ssh tunnel in the following way:

```
sudo ssh -J user1@intermediate_destination -NL 22:localhost:22 user2@destination
```

Then, I've tried to create a "Network folder" using Dolphin with the following parameters:

- **Type of network folder**: Secure shell (ssh)
- **Name**: whatever
- **User**: user2
- **Server**: localhost
- **Port**: 22
- **Protocol**: sftp
- **Folder**: dir2
- **Encoding**: Unicode (UTF-8)

And it finally worked!